# Dynamically creating a new set for each iteration of a while loop

Tags: python, sql, loops, set

I would like to create a unique set for each iteration of a while loop. This while loop is nested inside of a for loop that does epoch conversions, etc., and creates a list that has the values associated with that particular entry in the list.

I would like in the nested while, to create a unique set for the values that are being generated, I'm not sure how to approach this, as I've been looking at using a dictionary, but that doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.

The code in its current form is here:

```
for(call_start_time, call_end_time, sid) in cursor:
    call_delta = divmod((call_end_time - call_start_time).total_seconds(), 60)
    call_start_epoch = mktime(call_start_time.timetuple())
    call_end_epoch = mktime(call_end_time.timetuple())
    call_duration = (call_end_time - call_start_time).total_seconds()
    list_test = (sid, call_start_epoch, call_end_epoch, call_duration)

    while call_start_epoch <= call_end_epoch:
        call_duration_two = call_start_epoch + 60
        call_start_epoch += 60
        call_range_set.add(call_duration_two)
```

I haven't had much success with trying to get around this problem, and I'd appreciate any advice on this.

Comment: I may misunderstand you (if then please clarify your question), but what is the point of creating "a unique set for each of the values" - which implies each set has one single value ?

Comment: Sorry, creates a unique set for the values generated in the while loop. I'll update the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a, well ... `Set`

```
from sets import Set
...
call_range_set = Set()
while call_start_epoch <= call_end_epoch:
    call_duration_two = call_start_epoch + 60
    call_start_epoch += 60
    call_range_set.add(call_duration_two)
...
```

For more information, here's the [official documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html).

Comment: I am using a set, it's defined and set above in my code. I'm trying to create a unique set for each iteration of the loop and I'm not sure exactly how to do that in python, and if that is the right choice if I can do something less.....terrible.

Comment: But this (the code above) will create a unique set for each iteration of the for loop. In other words, it will create a set before the while loop runs, add everything that the while loop generates to it, and then you are free to do whatever you want with that set. A new set will again be created for the next for loop iteration and so on.

Comment: oh wow, sorry about that, I missed the ... after the from and thought the set create was at the top of the program rather then in the for loop itself. I'll test it out.

EDIT: And it does what I want, wow, thanks for pointing me in the direction I want.

Comment: `Sets` module is deprecated. There is a builtin set data-structure in python.